# how to upgrade PostgreSQL 9.2.15 to 9.2.18 on a rhel6 linux server

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

We are using PostgreSQL 9.2.15 on our rhel6 linux server, and I want to upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.2.18.

Please let me know steps to upgrade minor versions in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You essentially just tell your package manager (yum, apt-get, ...) to update the package.

Comment: Please do not change your question to mean something completely different - that makes the answers you got completely wrong. If you have a question about major version upgrades, ask a new question. But that is better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible.

Your best bet is probably to take the source RPM, replace 9.2.24 with 9.2.18 in the spec file, drop in the 9.2.18 source archive (which is available), and build your own RPM.

But, as has been mentioned in the comments, you should upgrade both databases to 9.2.24. Actually, you should upgrade to version 10.1 or 9.6.6.

Comment: Replace the file `postgresql-9.2.24.tar.gz` from the SRPM with `postgresql-9.2.18.tar.gz` that you download.

Comment: Right, that's what I said. The SRPM will contain 9.2.24. You'll have to download the 9.2.18 source from http://www.postgresql.org.

Comment: @user4287146: because .18 is obsolete and is no longer available as a "release" because that has been replaced with .24

Comment: Right, it is no longer available for download as a binary release.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for now all the reasons why doing this is a bad idea

it's absolutely possible to upgrade to versions other than the latest, but first you will need a copy of the version you want to install

then you use your low-level package manager `rpm -i packagefile`  or `dpkg -i packagefile` etc as apropriate...